# Create One-To-One relationship between table and view in EF4?

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have a table Item (ItemId int PK, Title vc, Description vc)

I created a testing view called ItemView: SELECT * FROM Item.

I added this view to my model, removed all the keys but the real key, added a 1-1 association, and mapped it, but I get 2 errors:

1. The table/view 'dbo.ItemView' does not have a primary key defined. The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view.
2. Error 3021: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line xxxx: Each of the following columns in table Item is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties:
   Item.ItemId is mapped to  
   What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edmx Views Processor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d9b76b5d-d45c-4e79-8d28-31444be582de) - a hotfix for this issue.